# Proving that a certain graph contains a 4-cycle

Tags: graphs

> Show that if $G$ is a graph with $|E| \geq 2|V|^{3/2}$, then $G$ must contain a $4$-cycle

Can someone explain/point me in the right direction on this?
Let's say we say $|V|= 4$, using the equation above we get $|E|= 16$.

I drew it out and I was unable to come up with $16$ edges. Do I completely misunderstand the graph equation?

Comment: Ok, so set V to 5.

Comment: and E becomes 22.5????

Comment: Note that a graph may contain an edge from a vertex to itself. Does that help?

Comment: Jules, unless it is explicitly stated that graphs may contain self-loops (edges from a vertex to itself), it's usually assumed that they don't.

Answer (score 4):

The question says "**IF** $G$ contains a certain number of edges, then..." and, as you've demonstrated, if $G$ has only four vertices, then it can't contain that many edges, since a graph (without self-loops) can contain at most $\tfrac12|V|\,(|V|-1)$ edges. So, for the condition to be true, we must have
$$\begin{align*}
    2|V|^{3/2} &\leq \tfrac12|V|\,(|V|-1) \\
    4|V|^{1/2} &\leq |V|-1 &\text{(dividing through by $\tfrac12|V|$)}\\
    16|V| &\leq |V|^2-2|V| + 1 &\text{(squaring both sides)}\\
    |V|^2-18|V|+1&\geq 0 &\text{(collecting terms)}
\end{align*}$$

Then, by the quadratic formula, we see that $|V|\geq 9 + 4\sqrt5 \approx 17.94$ (or $|V|\leq9-4\sqrt5$ but we're only interested in positive solutions for $|V|$).
It's not a problem that $17.94$ isn't an integer: the number of vertices must be greater than or equal to that number, so we actually have $|V|\geq 18$.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that part! But how about do i prove that within those 18 vertices a 4 cycle exists?

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer If $4 \le \mid V \mid < 18$, you can regard that this proposition is vacuously valid.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical question in graph theory, especially in extremal graph theory which studies extremal (maximal or minimal) graphs which satisfy a certain property.

A **dual problem** of your *prime* question is:

> What is the maximum possible number of edges in an undirected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices which does not contain $C_4$?

The [answer (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremal_graph_theory#Density_results) is $\left(\frac{1}{2} + o(1) \right) n^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

You can find a quite simple proof (based on *double counting*) for it in the [article: Theorem 2.4 for a slightly tighter result $|E| \le \frac{n}{4} (1 + \sqrt{4n-3})$](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/EC_Book_2nd/sample/44-49.pdf).

*Edit:* As stated by @David Richerby, your proposition is "well-defined" only if $|V| \ge 18$. If $4 \le |V| < 18$, you can regard that this proposition is vacuously valid. Note that, however, the *dual* problem above does not require $|V| \ge 18$.